# How do I center a div?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to center DIV in DIV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-div-in-div)

Sounds simple but couldn't figure it out:

How do I center a fixed width div on a page?

By default, it goes to the left.

halign is deprecated but I can find a could replacement.

[update]

```
width:800px;left-margin:auto;right-margin:auto:
```

works great.

Is there a way to do this without setting a fixed width?

Comment: [So many duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=center+div).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<style>
.centered {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
</style>

<div class="centered">
Some text
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="margin:0 auto">content here</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A div, by default, is the entire width of the page.  You can center the contents by setting the css of the div to:

```
.mydiv
{
    text-align: center;
}
```

OR

You can center the div itself by doing this:

```
.mydiv
{
    display: inline-block; /* make it be only as wide as its contents */
    margin: auto; /* centering magic by making the margins equal and maximum */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can center any div that doesn't span the entire page.  Say your div is

```
.div {
width: 80%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Then it will work fine.  As Evan said "display: inline-block;" will make the div as wide as its contents which will also work great with "margin: 0 auto;".

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`margin:auto;` should do the trick, I guess?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have an appropriate doctype declared, centering a div on a page should be as easy as:

```
#someDiv {
    width: 624px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

If you're using IE and you don't have a doctype declared (you're running in quirks mode), this won't work. The fix is to add the appropriate doctype declaration to your page. You can find the appropriate declaration here:

[W3C QA - Recommended list of Doctype declarations you can use in your Web document](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html)

Comment: What is the appropriate doctype?

Comment: @evan - That all depends on what kind of document you're creating.

Answer (score 0):

There's generally two ways of doing (that I've seen).  One with the margin attribute and another with positioning and `left:50%`

http://jsfiddle.net/NvaEE/

```
<br>
<div class="first"> I have a fixe dwidth</div>
<br>
<div class="second"> I have a fixe dwidth</div>

div{width:200px; background:#ddd;}

div.first{margin:0 auto;}
div.second{position:absolute;left:50%;margin-left:-100px}
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrap it in a container div that spans the width of the page and give that container div the

```
text-align: center;
```

css attribute.

There are other methods, such as managing the margins and widths.  For most cases, you can get by with text-align.